# App Starting Page UI Questions

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a couple of simple UI questions in regards to the initial app screen I am designing:

(a) How can I make the gray box surrounding the 'Join...' and 'Sign...' buttons transparent?

(b) Are there varying degrees of transparency?

(c) When I change between portrait and landscape orientation, my buttons disappear. How can I keep them visible?

[Portrait UI...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stdWh.png)

[Landscape UI...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrfBB.png)

(d) How do I add 'Company XYZ' to the TextView and have it centered above my two buttons inside the gray box?

Below is my current code...

My activity_main.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.companyxyz.companyxyz_0002.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My content_main.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="48dp"
    android:paddingRight="48dp"
    android:paddingTop="368dp"
    android:paddingBottom="48dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context="com.companyxyz.companyxyz_0002.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#eee"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="40dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="Join Free"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:text="Sign In"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: C) I would start by removing the absurd amount of padding on your root LinearLayout

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it did nothing to improve the visibility of the buttons in landscape orientation. Plus, I am trying to go for ease-of-use on user thumbs...it's not really an absurd amount of padding.

Comment: It's padding, so it is inside the layout, meaning it creates an empty void between it and the other layouts. Margin is outside the layout. I guess it isn't absurd for 4K resolution phones these days, but still, if you want to force the buttons to the bottom of the screen for "thumb" access, use a RelativeLayout

Comment: I set the padding to 8dp on the parent layout and the buttons don't show. Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 0):

**A & B**: The format for the `android:background` is hex ARGB, (alpha-red-green-blue), so what you currently have is the same as `#FFeeeeee`, which is full alpha and grey. Knock that `FF` (256) down to `00` (0), and it will be fully transparent. So, yes, there are "varying degrees of transparency".

**C & D**: I've striped all the padding and extra stuff from your `content_main.xml`, changed to a RelativeLayout and I got this. Let me know if you wanted something different. I also added the login fields to demonstrate the layout anchoring features of RelativeLayout.

Note, you'll need to add stuff back-in like `xmlns:tools=...` and `tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"`

[image: portrait]
[image: landscape]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <!-- Sign in Form -->
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Username"
                android:labelFor="@id/edit_username"/>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/edit_username"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Password"
                android:labelFor="@id/edit_password"/>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/edit_password"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Button Bar -->
    <LinearLayout
            android:background="#77eeeeee"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <TextView
                android:text="Pick an action"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:id="@+id/registrationButtonRow"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Join Free"
                    android:id="@+id/btn_register"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Sign In"
                    android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your `paddingTop` of 368dp which you have given it to the `LinearLyaout` in `content_main`. When you rotates to screen from vertical to horizontal this padding push the view out side of the visible region. You need to adjust this padding for the landscape mode with different layout or you can adjust it with the `RelativeLayout` as suggested in other answers.